# Video shows white screen while using video.play()

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I want to play a video file on a website and i have this function through which i am trying to do it

```
function closePageWithCountdown(seconds) {
  const countdownElement = document.createElement("countdowntime");
  countdownElement.style.position = "fixed";
  countdownElement.style.top = "0";
  countdownElement.style.left = "0";
  countdownElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  countdownElement.style.color = "white";
  countdownElement.style.padding = "5px";

  document.body.appendChild(countdownElement);

  function updateCountdown() {
    countdownElement.textContent = `Page will automatically close in ${seconds} seconds`;

    if (seconds === 0) {
      document.body.removeChild(countdownElement);
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();
      document.write('Resource Exhausted !\n<br>You may reload the page or close the tab.');
      var centeredText = document.createElement("div");
      centeredText.innerHTML = "Some Text Here";
      centeredText.style.position = "fixed";
      centeredText.style.bottom = "0";
      centeredText.style.left = "0";
      centeredText.style.right = "0";
      centeredText.style.textAlign = "center";
      // centeredText.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8";
      centeredText.style.padding = "10px";
      centeredText.style.zIndex = "999"; // Ensures it appears on top of other content
      
      // Append the element to the body
      document.body.appendChild(centeredText);

      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
      
      var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']; // List of rainbow colors
      var colorIndex = 0; // Initialize color index

      function flash() {
            centeredText.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
            colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length; // Cycle through colors
      }

      var clr = setInterval(flash, 500);
      
      // Create a new div element to hold the text
      var flashbackText = document.createElement('div');
      flashbackText.innerHTML = 'Click here to watch';
      flashbackText.style.position = 'absolute';
      flashbackText.style.top = '50%';
      flashbackText.style.left = '50%';
      flashbackText.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
      flashbackText.style.fontSize = '1.5em';
      flashbackText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      flashbackText.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      flashbackText.style.padding = '10px';
      flashbackText.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      flashbackText.style.zIndex = '1000'; // Ensure it's above other elements

      // Append the text to the body
      document.body.appendChild(flashbackText);
    
      // Event listener for the click event
      flashbackText.addEventListener('click', function() {
       // Clear the screen
       document.body.innerHTML = '';

       // Create a video element
       var video = document.createElement('video');
       video.id = 'myVideo';
       video.style.position = 'absolute';
       video.style.top = '50%';
       video.style.left = '50%';
       video.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg)'; // Rotate the video 90 degrees
       video.style.width = '100vh'; // Use viewport height as width for landscape
       video.style.height = '100vw'; // Use viewport width as height for landscape
       video.style.objectFit = 'contain'; // Ensure it covers the full area
       video.autoplay = true;
       video.controls = false; // Hide controls

       // Set the source of the video
       var source = document.createElement('source');
       source.src = './myvideo.mp4'; // Replace with the path to your video
       source.type = 'video/mp4';

       // Append source to video element
       video.appendChild(source);

       // Add the video to the screen
       document.body.appendChild(video);

       video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
         console.log('Video metadata loaded successfully');
         console.log('Video duration:', video.duration);
       }; 
       video.onerror = function() {
        console.error('Error loading the video');
       };      
        
       // Play the video
       video.play();

       // Event listener for when the video ends
       video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        // Clear the video and show the original text again
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
        document.body.appendChild(flashbackText);
        document.body.appendChild(centeredText);
        document.write('Resource Exhausted !\n<br>You may reload the page or close the tab.');
       });    
      });
           

    } else {
      seconds--;
      setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    }
  }

  updateCountdown();
}
closePageWithCountdown(1) // 1 sec for testing
```

**Expected behaviour**: There is a highlighted text (on the center of screen) on which if the user clicks it plays a video and when the video ends it simply returns to the old content of the page.

However on the site it shows a white screen and no sound.

I don't know what wrong i am doing here is it that i didn't include any `<video>` tag in my index.html file?

Also i am not getting any console log for `video.onloadedmetadata` and `video.onerror`

(Note: It work sometime when I used a telegra.ph video link as the source.src)

Comment: Are you sure about `document.createElement("countdowntime")`?  As far as I know document.createElement requires a HTML tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is an `undefined` variable and trying to reference it crashes your script. You need to set the properties of `video` instead and of course you only need to add `video` to your HTML. At the end of your counter you display that the resource has been exhausted, which is incorrect, because the resource works properly. You don't need to remove your HTML's first child nor to add that text when the counter finishes its job. You only need to do it when the video ends. See the snippet below:

```js
function closePageWithCountdown(seconds) {
  const countdownElement = document.createElement("countdowntime");
  countdownElement.style.position = "fixed";
  countdownElement.style.top = "0";
  countdownElement.style.left = "0";
  countdownElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  countdownElement.style.color = "white";
  countdownElement.style.padding = "5px";

  document.body.appendChild(countdownElement);

  function updateCountdown() {
    countdownElement.textContent = `Page will automatically close in ${seconds} seconds`;

    if (seconds === 0) {
      document.body.removeChild(countdownElement);
      //document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].remove();
      //document.write('Resource Exhaustedd !\n<br>You may reload the page or close the tab.');
      var centeredText = document.createElement("div");
      centeredText.innerHTML = "Some Text Here";
      centeredText.style.position = "fixed";
      centeredText.style.bottom = "0";
      centeredText.style.left = "0";
      centeredText.style.right = "0";
      centeredText.style.textAlign = "center";
      // centeredText.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8";
      centeredText.style.padding = "10px";
      centeredText.style.zIndex = "999"; // Ensures it appears on top of other content
      
      // Append the element to the body
      document.body.appendChild(centeredText);

      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
      
      var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']; // List of rainbow colors
      var colorIndex = 0; // Initialize color index

      function flash() {
            centeredText.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
            colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length; // Cycle through colors
      }

      var clr = setInterval(flash, 500);
      
      // Create a new div element to hold the text
      var flashbackText = document.createElement('div');
      flashbackText.innerHTML = 'Click here to watch';
      flashbackText.style.position = 'absolute';
      flashbackText.style.top = '50%';
      flashbackText.style.left = '50%';
      flashbackText.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
      flashbackText.style.fontSize = '1.5em';
      flashbackText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      flashbackText.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      flashbackText.style.padding = '10px';
      flashbackText.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      flashbackText.style.zIndex = '1000'; // Ensure it's above other elements

      // Append the text to the body
      document.body.appendChild(flashbackText);
    
      // Event listener for the click event
      flashbackText.addEventListener('click', function() {
       // Clear the screen
       document.body.innerHTML = '';

       // Create a video element
       var video = document.createElement('video');
       video.id = 'myVideo';
       video.style.position = 'absolute';
       video.style.top = '50%';
       video.style.left = '50%';
       video.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg)'; // Rotate the video 90 degrees
       video.style.width = '100vh'; // Use viewport height as width for landscape
       video.style.height = '100vw'; // Use viewport width as height for landscape
       video.style.objectFit = 'contain'; // Ensure it covers the full area
       video.autoplay = true;
       video.controls = false; // Hide controls

       // Set the source of the video
       //var source = document.createElement('source');
       //source.src = './myvideo.mp4'; // Replace with the path to your video
       video.src = 'https://telegra.ph/file/9d80fe1d60b2896d8b47b.mp4'; // Replace with the path to your video
       video.type = 'video/mp4';
       //source.type = 'video/mp4';

       // Append source to video element
       //document..appendChild(source);

       // Add the video to the screen
       document.body.appendChild(video);

       video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
         console.log('Video metadata loaded successfully');
         console.log('Video duration:', video.duration);
       }; 
       video.onerror = function() {
        console.error('Error loading the video');
       };      
        
       // Play the video
       video.play();

       // Event listener for when the video ends
       video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        // Clear the video and show the original text again
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
        document.body.appendChild(flashbackText);
        document.body.appendChild(centeredText);
        document.write('Resource Exhausted !\n<br>You may reload the page or close the tab.');
       });    
      });
           

    } else {
      seconds--;
      setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    }
  }

  updateCountdown();
}
closePageWithCountdown(1) // 1 sec for testing
```

```html
<div id="countdowntime"></div>
```

Comment: What i figured out is that the issue is specific to videos with very low frame rates try with this one https://telegra.ph/file/9d80fe1d60b2896d8b47b.mp4

Comment: @stranger555 I have edited my answer and added your new video. Please try it. If it solves your issue, then you can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.

Answer (score 1):

When I grab your code and add in a test video, the code seems to be doing what you're intending.

Since a result pops up with another video link, my assumption is the issue is with the video you're referencing or the file path you're using to reference the video.

```js
   var video = document.createElement('video');
   video.id = 'myVideo';
   video.style.position = 'absolute';
   video.style.top = '50%';
   video.style.left = '50%';
   video.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg)'; // Rotate the video 90 degrees
   video.style.width = '100vh'; // Use viewport height as width for landscape
   video.style.height = '100vw'; // Use viewport width as height for landscape
   video.style.objectFit = 'contain'; // Ensure it covers the full area
   video.autoplay = true;
   video.controls = false; // Hide controls

   // Set the source of the video
   var source = document.createElement('source');
   source.src = 'https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4'; // Replace with the path to your video
   source.type = 'video/mp4';

   // Append source to video element
   video.appendChild(source);

   // Add the video to the screen
   document.body.appendChild(video);

   video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
     console.log('Video metadata loaded successfully');
     console.log('Video duration:', video.duration);
   }; 
   video.onerror = function() {
    console.error('Error loading the video');
   };      
    
   // Play the video
   video.play();
```

Comment: The path is correct i am sure about that. I don't know what is the problem. Have you noticed that in the above snippet the video shows up but doesn't play (it's just showing a still image). I think there is something else going wrong while decoding the video.

Comment: I have provided the entire function maybe i have done something wrong in the function itself?

Comment: I would specifically check your source.src; this is all I changed.

Comment: Take the source.src as any file/external link. I just checked out that the chunk of code i gave previously works fine with the source.src seperately but inside the closePageWithCountdown() function there is something wrong which is preventing the video from playing. I have written the expected behaviour on below the block of code.

Answer (score 0):

When you set **document.body.innerHTML** to an empty string, you are effectively removing all existing elements, including the script that triggers video playback. This may cause unexpected behavior.

Instead of clearing the entire **document.body**, consider creating a container element to hold both the video and the original text. You can then replace the content of that container with the video and revert to the original text when needed. Here's a modified version of your code to illustrate this

```
function closePageWithCountdown(seconds) {
  const countdownElement = document.createElement("countdowntime");
  countdownElement.style.position = "fixed";
  countdownElement.style.top = "0";
  countdownElement.style.left = "0";
  countdownElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  countdownElement.style.color = "white";
  countdownElement.style.padding = "5px";

  document.body.appendChild(countdownElement);

  function updateCountdown() {
    countdownElement.textContent = `Page will automatically close in ${seconds} seconds`;

    if (seconds === 0) {
      document.body.removeChild(countdownElement);

      // Create a container to hold the video and original text
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.style.position = 'absolute';
      container.style.top = '0';
      container.style.left = '0';
      container.style.width = '100%';
      container.style.height = '100%';
      container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      // Original text
      var centeredText = document.createElement("div");
      centeredText.innerHTML = "Some Text Here";
      centeredText.style.position = "fixed";
      centeredText.style.bottom = "0";
      centeredText.style.left = "0";
      centeredText.style.right = "0";
      centeredText.style.textAlign = "center";
      centeredText.style.padding = "10px";
      centeredText.style.zIndex = "999"; // Ensures it appears on top of other content
      container.appendChild(centeredText);

      // Video container
      var videoContainer = document.createElement('div');
      videoContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
      videoContainer.style.top = '0';
      videoContainer.style.left = '0';
      videoContainer.style.width = '100%';
      videoContainer.style.height = '100%';
      container.appendChild(videoContainer);

      // Event listener for the click event
      centeredText.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Create a video element
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.id = 'myVideo';
        video.style.width = '100%';
        video.style.height = '100%';
        video.style.objectFit = 'contain'; // Ensure it covers the full area
        video.autoplay = true;
        video.controls = false; // Hide controls

        // Set the source of the video
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.src = './myvideo.mp4'; // Replace with the path to your video
        source.type = 'video/mp4';

        // Append source to video element
        video.appendChild(source);

        // Add the video to the container
        videoContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content
        videoContainer.appendChild(video);

        video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
          console.log('Video metadata loaded successfully');
          console.log('Video duration:', video.duration);
        };
        video.onerror = function () {
          console.error('Error loading the video');
        };

        // Event listener for when the video ends
        video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
          // Revert to the original text
          videoContainer.innerHTML = '';
          container.appendChild(centeredText);
          document.write('Resource Exhausted !\n<br>You may reload the page or close the tab.');
        });
      });

    } else {
      seconds--;
      setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    }
  }

  updateCountdown();
}
closePageWithCountdown(1); // 1 sec for testing
```